# How did the necromancer fool the healers through magic barrier?

Tags: magic, science-fiction, mythical-creatures

We're living in a ~medieval fantasy world, you can just imagine it as the tolkien universe.

The biggest castle in the kingdom is protected by a magic barrier and the king never left the castle. Let's take for fact that there is absolutely no way that a necromancer could curse the king because of that magic barrier, besides for one item which is explained later.

People are pretty confident that the magic barrier is safe, but somehow the king got very ill. The necromancer fooled everyone into thinking that he cursed the king.

Background for the illusion of the curse is that the necromancer wants to have a magic cube escorted to the king. The magic cube can pass the magic barrier, no matter what's the content... -> Content is the actual curse!

How could the necromancer achieve that?

Ways I thought of, but which don't satisfy me enough:

- King got a veeery rare illness so the healers in the castle (who are the absolutely best healers in the whole kingdom) couldn't find out what it is -> Don't like the idea that the healers couldn't figure out it's just an illness and not a curse
- Necromancer is manipulating the healers -> So he could also just manipulate the healers to kill the king, so this is not an option
- Necromancer poisened food which is gathered outside of the castle -> The king got people who taste the food, so there would be multiple people ill and everyone would know it came from the food and not from a curse

I highly prefer an answer which makes the necromancer do an action which leads to the king being weakened, but this option can only weaken him and not kill him. His ultimate goal is to kill him.

This is my first question here, hope that's a right kind of question and I'm looking forward for these awesome answers this community always provides!

Comment: So, after the "cursed" cube reached the King and coincidentally the King become ill, the necromancer will claim responsibility and declare that he has successfully cursed the King? Is this correct?

Comment: @Vylix Yes. Necromancer will reveal that the king wasn't actually cursed until when heal cube reached the king, which will lead to the knights thinking that the ones who escorted the cube are servants of the necromancer (even if they really are not and thought that's a heal in the cube)

Answer (score 3):

**Inside agent.**

1. **[Stooge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stooge)** of necromancer.  This could be someone who is bullied or bribed or coerced to do something that makes the king sick.  There are any number of ways that a necromancer might co-erce some civilian with access to the king to do his bidding.
2. **Clever third party**.  I like this best because it is surprising.  The king gets sick in an inexplicable way.  By the nature of the sickness seems clear that it is the doing of the necromancer.  The necromancer is very much caught by surprise by this turn of events but rolls with it, claiming responsibility.  It is not good timing for the necromancer's scheme and he does not have the advantage that he would with a curse.  It is, however, very good timing for the princess whom no-one suspects - she is well known to hate the necromancer, who in any event has claimed responsibility.  The grieving princess takes control from her ailing father (whom she will ensure does not recover) and leads the outraged military against the necromancer, who is struggling to get organized on short notice.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a *smuggling* problem than a necromancy problem.  We need a way for someone to carry the cube into the castle and give it to the king.

Some thoughts:

1. **Every kingdom has enemies** -- Necromancer gets in touch with the embassy of a rival kingdom.  Either makes an alliance with them, or magics them into including the cube with their basket of diplomatic gifts.
2. **Br'er Rabbit** -- Necromancer puts a sickness curse on *someone else*.  Someone the King values.  Necromancer loudly declares that he will **never** surrender his "Athelas Box", with which the hands of a King can cure any disease.  The feisty Princess and a picked squad of adventurers infiltrates the necromancer's Dark Lair and *steal* the cube, while the necromancer wails about being defeated, the back of his hand pressed to his forehead.  The Princess triumphantly delivers the cube to her father...